# OData4j sample implementation for POST/Create operations

Tags: odata4j

Where can I find sample implementaion for OData Create operation (POST in REST) using odata4j for POJO. I have already checked InMemoryProducerExample but no help.
Also some pointers on how to use $filter for Query operations...

Thanks in advance, Avishek.